# Why C++ strtod parses "708530856168225829.3221614e9" to 7.08530856168225898e+26 instead of 7.08530856168225761e+26?

Tags: parsing, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

While writing a custom floating point number parser (for speed reasons) and checking the precision against `strtod` (that I assume to be extremely accurate) I found that sometimes the naive approach of using

```
 number = (int_part + dec_part/pow(10., no_of_decs)) * pow(10., expo)
```

seems to be actually "more accurate" (when computation is done using `long double` and then result converted back to a double) than `strtod` result and that is surprising.

Do official IEEE754 parsing rules actually mandate a less accurate result?

For example with the string

```
 708530856168225829.3221614e9
```

the naive computation gives

```
 7.08530856168225761e+26
```

that seems closer than result of `strtod`

```
 7.08530856168225898e+26
```

to the "theoretical" result (that cannot be represented exactly by a 64-bit `double`)

```
 7.085308561682258293221614e+26
```

(experiments were done with `g++ (GCC) 10.2.0` and `clang++ 11.1.0` on Arch linux, and they both agree on ...898e+26 for `strtod` and `...761e+26` for naive computation)

Comment: For completeness, I think it would be good to mention which libc implementations you tried. (I assume you tried more than one.)

Comment: @rici: added a note on compilers used

Comment: "Do official IEEE754 parsing rules actually mandate a less accurate result?" --> No.

Comment: @6502: Thanks. But `strtod` is part of the library, and on most Linux installs, gcc and clang use the same library (glibc). Further to Eric Postpischil's excellent answer, using `%a` format can provide a lot more insight than trying to guess the precise double from a decimal representation.

Comment: @rici: I'm a linux user but I don't dig too much into system level stuff, I'm also on a rolling distro so telling which version I'm running of something is harder than in other cases. My mistake was indeed at a very logic level and for sure not a bug (and I never thought it was). Mine was a gross mistake: I knew `"%.18g"` was accurate enough to parse a double back correctly, but that doesn't make it exact! Yet I was still making computations and reasoning using those digits as the real value of the double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note, 7.085308561682258293221614e+26 is not representable in IEEE-754 double precision (binary64). Therefore, it is not a candidate result and plays no role in determining the result.

The two numbers representable binary64 closest to 708530856168225829.3221614e9 are 708530856168225760595673088 and 708530856168225898034626560. Writing out the original fully and lining them up for inspection with original in the middle, we have:

```
708530856168225760595673088   representable value below original
708530856168225829322161400   original number
708530856168225898034626560   representable value above original
```

Subtracting gives the absolute differences between the lower and the original and between the original and the higher:

```
                68726488312   distance to lower
                68712465160   distance to higher
```

and therefore the higher number, 708530856168225898034626560, is closer to the original. This is in fact the result you report, and therefore the software is behaving correctly.

Observe that it is a mistake to think of binary64 in decimal without all significant digits. Writing out the partial decimal numerals as we did the full numbers above, we have:

```
7.08530856168225761e+26         proposed result
7 08530856168225829.3221614e9   original number
7.08530856168225898e+26         reported result of strtod
```

with differences:

```
                 68322161400   distance to lower
                 68677838600   distance to higher
```

Thus, rounding the actual values of the floating-point numbers to decimal numerals without all the digits introduced errors and portrayed incorrect values. Binary floating-point numbers **are not** and **do not represent** decimal numerals, and displaying them without all significant digits shows incorrect values.

Comment: Makes perfect sense... I was using `"%.18g"` to display the numbers and while this produces a representation that parses back to the correct `double` value it does not represent correctly the `double` in decimal, so making computations and reasoning based on the `"%.18g"` representation gives wrong answers. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

The value 708530856168225829.3221614e9 is between 2 `double`.

```
7.08530856168225 760 59567309...e+26 // lower double
7.08530856168225 829 31514982...e+26 // half way
7 08530856168225 829.3221614e9       // OP's code
7.08530856168225 898 03462656...e+26 // upper double
1 23456789012345 678 90              // Significant digit count
```

It is *very* nearly halfway between those 2 `double`.

In this case I say 7.08530856168225 898 03462656...e+26 from `strtod()` is the better answer and OP's *naïve computation* is inferior and due to the cumulative rounding errors injected by the division, multiplication and addition.

---

Note: IEEE754 parsing does not require infinite precision in parsing text.  It is required to use *at least* N+3 significant decimal digits.  (I believe N==17) for [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) AKA `double`.

When using truncated text to convert, the answer may differ from using more digits in nearly half-way cases.  Still, in this case, even truncating to 20 digits, the upper `double` is the better choice.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think it is the other way around.  IEEE-754 defines it.  Later I'll dig up the ref.  I find it humorous that we have nearly simultaneously approached the answer in  similar ways.

Comment: You are correct, the relevant specification is in IEEE-754. But it is not saying an implementation does not have to use “infinitely precise” arithmetic in the conversions, just that the number of digits that can be converted with correct rounding may be limited. That is, it might be only capable of producing 17 digits for binary64, but they must be correct (that is, calculated as if with “infinitely precise” arithmetic before rounding).

Comment: @EricPostpischil For completeness concerning truncating: "There might be an implementation-defined limit on the number of significant digits that can be converted with correct rounding to and from supported binary formats. That limit, H, shall be such that H ≥ M+ 3 and it should be that H is unbounded."  754_2019-2008 5.12.2.